# Как определить создателя беседы через VK API?

Tags: php, json, vkontakte-api, callback

В ВК с помощью метода `messages.getConversationMembers` можно получить список участников беседы и их статус в беседе в виде JSON. К примеру:

```
{
"member_id": 254697359,
"invited_by": 254697359,
"is_admin": true,
"is_owner": true,
"join_date": 1542471385
}, {
"member_id": 221601776,
"invited_by": 254697359,
"is_admin": true,
"join_date": 1542648439
}
```

Если `is_onwer = true` - Пользователь создатель беседы

**Вопрос:**

Как можно определить из всего этого списка создателя беседы и вывести его `member_id`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAdmin($peer_id, $token, $from_id) {
    if($from_id == "126399522") {
        return true;
    } else {
        $users_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getConversationMembers?peer_id={$peer_id}&access_token={$token}&v=5.92"));
        for($i = 0; $i < $users_info->response->count; $i++) {
            if($users_info->response->items[$i]->member_id == $from_id && $users_info->response->items[$i]->is_admin) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Моя функция для проверки на администратора, для создателя нужно чутка переписать. Первое условие отвечает, что даже я администратор, даже если таковым не являюсь.